# Direct links to all LaTeX packages

Tags: packages, miktex, windows, ctan, repositories

Because of proxy limitations in MiKTeX Console, I need to download each LaTeX package from a browser, and move it to my local repository.

Most online CTAN mirrors are organized in a very cluttered folder structure.

Some time ago, I had found an http repository which had all up-to-date LaTeX packages listed on a single page, which I could then order by date and simply download each `.tar.gz` package newer than the last date I updated my installation.

Can someone link me to this repository?

Comment: ctan is by design not organised in the file structure needed fro installation. Downloading from ctan by hand when miktex and texlive have done all the installlation re-organisation already is very odd, why not get a texlive iso image and just instll the whole thing?

Comment: any mirror that you can reach by ftp should be fine, see here for a list of mirrors https://ctan.org/mirrors, you only need to click you then through to /systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Perfect, that folder seem like what I had used. My proxy also blocks ftp, but I found a mirror that uses an http interface for the folder structure:
http://ftp.fau.de/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/?C=M;O=D

Would you like to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Answer applies to Windows machines.

All LaTeX package files are found in the file structure under

```
/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
```

To get to the list as http, append the string above to any of the CTAN mirrors listed on the [CTAN mirror page](https://ctan.org/mirrors), for example:

- http://ctan.mirror.norbert-ruehl.de/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
- http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
- http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/

To download the packages, you can either click on the required packages, or use a browser plugin.

"[uSelect iDownload](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/uselect-idownload/ileabdhfjmgaognikmjgmhhkjffggejc)" for Chrome allows to draw selection boxes around download links, and download all selected files in one go.

Those files can then be saved in a folder, e.g. called "repo", which can then be selected in the MiKTeX Console as the repository.